# JavaScript: performance constraints of `delete` keyword

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm trying to better learn how JS works under the hood and I've heard in the past that the `delete` keyword (specifically node.js or browsers using V8) results in poor performance, so I want to see if I can figure out what the benefits/detriments are for using that keyword.

I believe the reasoning for not using `delete` is that removing a property leads to a rebuilding of hidden class transitions and thus a recompiling of the inline cache. However, I believe it is also true that the object prototype will no longer enumerate that property, so if the object is used heavily the upfront cost may eventually pay off.

So:

1. Are my assumptions about the tradeoffs correct?
2. If they are correct, is one factor more important than the other (e.g. is rebuilding the IC much more expensive than many prototype enumerations)?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/375

Comment: That's helpful too, thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*the object prototype will no longer enumerate that property*"? Can you share your code, please? Why are you concerned about enumerations?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

V8 developer here. Short answer: "it depends".

Having an unused property doesn't hurt; there is no general "enumeration cost" unless you actually perform explicit enumerations. In other words, an "enumeration cost" only exists if you find yourself doing something like this:

```
for (var p in object) {
  if (p === old_property_that_I_could_have_deleted) continue;
  /* process other properties... */
}
```

The key reason why it's hard to give a concrete answer (or to provide a canonical example where an effect would be measurable) is because the effects are non-local: they depend both on what exactly you're doing with the object in question, and on what the rest of your app is doing. Deleting a property from one object may well cause operations on other objects to become slower. Or faster. It depends.

To take a step back and look at the high-level situation: JavaScript as a language sort of assumes that objects are represented as dictionaries. Deleting an entry in a dictionary should be perfectly fine, which is why it makes sense that the `delete` operator exists. In practice, it turns out that an engine can achieve huge performance improvements for read-heavy apps, which is by far the most common case, if it does *not* store objects as dictionaries, but instead more like something that resembles C/C++ structs. However, such an object representation is (1) generally hard/inefficient to do when properties get deleted, and (2) the engine may well interpret even the first deletion of a property as a hint that the programmer wants this particular object to behave like a dictionary, so it might switch the internal representation over. If a fast-to-modify dictionary is what you wanted, then that's fine (it will provide a benefit even); however if you wanted the object to remain in slow-to-modify/fast-to-read mode, you would perceive the transition to fast-to-modify/slow-to-read dictionary mode as a performance problem.

Thankfully there is a great solution nowadays: when you want a dictionary, use a `Map` or `Set`. Engines can (and usually will) assume that you'll want to delete entries from these, so the implementations are optimized for making that possible without negative side effects; in particular no hidden classes are involved.

A few remarks on your assumptions: deleting a property makes an object (mostly) leave the system of hidden class transitions, no transitions will be rebuilt. There is no single global "inline cache", there are many inline caches sprinkled all over your functions. They don't get rebuilt, they just transition to slower and slower modes the more different cases they have to handle. (That's generally how caching works: caching a single case provides huge speedups; on the other end of the scale if you have as many different cases as executions, then a cache just wastes time and memory without providing any benefit.) Again the effect of dictionary-mode objects depends on the overall situation: an inline cache dealing with (mostly) dictionary-mode objects typically exhibits performance somewhere in between (1) an inline cache that only has to deal with objects sharing the single same hidden class, and (2) an inline cache that has to deal with hundreds or thousands of different hidden classes.

Comment: Are `Map` and `Set` consistently faster than using `Object.create(null)` for the equivalent purposes? Is V8 ever capable of optimizing away the function call overhead of `get()`, `set()`, `add()`, `has()` and `delete()`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Yes, `Map` and `Set` are consistently faster for dictionary use cases. Use them! If you think that using an object as a dictionary does not perform lots of function calls under the hood, then I have some bad news for you ;-)